# Ubuntu on Galaxy note 3 ?

Tags: galaxy-nexus

I have Samsung Galaxy Note 3. I wanna install Ubuntu on my phone.
Is that possible ? My phone has 64G SD Card.
Thanks.

Comment: just to be clear, the note 3 is not a galaxy nexus, even if it is by the same manufacturer. It would not be a full installation unless you have a way to dock it, in which case you would just use "ubuntu for android" which does not depend on model or manufacturer. If you are talking about ubuntu touch, you have to check for support, which is something that I do not see. A better place to check for a custom support version would be xda-developers.com

Comment: Thnaks for your comment. I couldn't find the tag 'Galaxy note'.

Comment: can I move that to the answer box?

Comment: And Im talking about Ubuntu for Android. Is it possilbe for Galaxy note 3 ?

Comment: I think you need it rooted, but yes

Comment: I've already done it. please help me more detail. thanks.

Comment: Hold on a moment or two, I've read about it but never really tried

Comment: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2608765 this is the only somewhat reputable source I can find, Ubuntu really dropped support for almost everything they supported already, which was pretty much just nexus devices to begin with. I'll see if I can find something in the morning that'll work, otherwise I'll see if I can pull together a port compile for you

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear, the note 3 is not a galaxy nexus, even if it is by the same manufacturer. It would not be a full installation unless you have a way to dock it, in which case you would just use "ubuntu for android" which does not depend on model or manufacturer. If you are talking about ubuntu touch, you have to check for support, which is something that I do not see. A better place to check for a custom support version would be xda-developers.com

Comment: please mark it as the answer if it is.